# Android Eclipse Action Bar Background Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I would like to add my own image background to the action bar. How can I do that? Also on top of this on the left I would like to add another image of my own which contains a text. Is this possible?

I haven't managed to find any examples of this at all.

I have got a **"styles.xml"**, in values folder, which contains the actual background image:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />

<style name="ActionBar">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
<item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I've also got an **"actionbarbg.xml"**, within the layout folder, which contains the text image I mentioned:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/ActionBar" >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="15dip"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/bannerlogo" />
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have an **"actionbar.xml"**, within the menu folder, which contains 2 menu buttons on the action bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
android:id="@+id/item_refresh"
android:icon="@drawable/help"
android:title="Refresh"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
android:id="@+id/item_save"
android:icon="@drawable/info"
android:title="Save"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

</menu>
```

My code within my main class:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbarbg, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Test result]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android 4.0 or higher?
Also, maybe it's easier doing it with the sherlock actionbar

Comment: I am using Android 4.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting the android:src and android:background, according to the requirements.

Comment: Where would I set this?

Comment: In their following .xml